# Is there any difference between an n-ary and an m-way tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

Perhaps it is a dumb question but I am confused with the following:
Are `n-ary trees` and `m-way trees` the same thing?
I see in various posts talk about `m-way` trees and other `n-ary` trees but I am not sure if these are the same data structures or are used for the same problems
Are they the same thing? Could someone please help me clear this out in my head?

Comment: No difference but some texts may say `m-way tree` and mean `m-way search tree`. That is different because it implies that the (n-1) keys are sorted and the children's keys are in specific order, too.

Comment: @ypercube:Ah, I see. You could put this as an anwer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-ary_tree):

> In graph theory, a k-ary tree is a rooted tree in which each node has
>   no more than k children. It is also sometimes known as a k-way tree,
>   an N-ary tree, or an M-ary tree. A binary tree is the special case
>   where k=2.

So the answer your question is: **Yes, it is the same thing.**

Answer (score 4):

If `n == m`, then there is no difference.